# Is it possible to keep alive request using Google App Engine urlfetch.Client

Tags: google-app-engine, go, urlfetch

I will create an API using Google App Engine (on golang).
API endpoint I will create publishes HTTP request.
The problem is that HTTP request in this endpoint cannot be keep-alive.

- Why?
- Is it possible to use keep-alive?

Sample source code is following.

https://github.com/suzuito/gae-example